# rounding lubridate period objects from DD:HH:MM:SS to HH:MM:SS

Tags: r, lubridate

I have an aggregated column containing lubridate period objects in the following form

```
sum_times
1d 15H 25M 0S
```

I want it to be in the HH:MM:SS form, meaning that if the hours exceed 24, I dont want to have days in my format but instead continue counting the hours. something that looks like this

```
sum_times
39H 25M 0S
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below example should take you in the right direction:

```
span <- interval(ymd_hms("2009-01-01 00:00:00"), ymd_hms("2010-02-02 01:01:01")) #interval
as.period(span, unit = "hour")
[1] "9529H 1M 1S"
as.period(span, unit = "day")
[1] "397d 1H 1M 1S"
```

Comment: I encountered a problem, the as.period() function ignores periods containing only minutes when i specify unit="hour".